# Cloudwatch Seems to Clobber Seconds

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Below is an example of data being sent to Cloudwatch.  When I look at the charts this creates, the Time axis appears to ignore seconds.  Values appear above the nearest minute they were posted instead of the actual start time.

For example, I know a start time was 10:45:07 but it appears on Cloudwatch as a point above 10:45:00.  I've set the resolution of the chart to 1 second and it still appears this way.

Why are seconds getting clobbered?

```
start = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)

response = client.put_metric_data(
    Namespace='etl-jobs',
    MetricData=[
        {
            'MetricName': 'added_jobs',
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                    'Name': 'length',
                    'Value': 'count'
                },
            ],
            'Timestamp': start,
            'Value': somevalue
        },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `StorageResolution` with a value of 1 to get high-resolution metrics. See [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDatum.html)